# What is the regulator ServiceType for?

Tags: corda

Just noticed there is a ServiceType of "regulator". Don't see any documentation on it. What is it for? I'm hoping it's a service that can see all transactions going through the system.

Answer (score 2):

This features has been retired as of Corda 3.1.

The idea was to allow a flow to quickly look up one or more regulators it needs to send the data to via the network map.

Here's an example from TwoPartyDealFlow.kt:

```
val regulators = serviceHub.networkMapCache.regulatorNodes
if (regulators.isNotEmpty()) {
    // Copy the transaction to every regulator in the network. This is obviously completely bogus, it's just for demo purposes.
    regulators.forEach { 
        send(it.serviceIdentities(ServiceType.regulator).first(), ftx)
    }
}
```

However, note that this approach is opt-in - there's currently nothing in the code that prevents the flow's author from not performing this step.